# line breaker in string inside another string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, kivy

i have string named `kv`.

inside that string i have another string named `text`, and `text` contain a line breaker.

my problem is that `kv` break the line also and don't want that, i want just the `text` string to break the line

```html
kv='''
BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        spacing: 50
        padding: 5

        Button:
            id: btn_aller
            text: "{} - {} \n [size=12](cliquez pour plus d'information)[/size]".format(root.depart, root.destination)
            bold: True
'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `\\n` instead of `\n`:

```
kv='''
BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        spacing: 50
        padding: 5

        Button:
            id: btn_aller
            text: "{} - {} \\n [size=12](cliquez pour plus d'information)[/size]".format(root.depart, root.destination)"
            bold: True
'''
```

`print(kv)` will show the following on the console:

```
BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        spacing: 50
        padding: 5

        Button:
            id: btn_aller
            text: "{} - {} \n [size=12](cliquez pour plus d'information)[/size]".format(root.depart, root.destination)"
            bold: True
```